# SQL Server group by max string column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make a query that groups me by the ID_Country, Year_, Employee_ID columns and applying a max to the Employee_Name column so that it returns the employee name with more characters but for each execution it returns different results.

table with employee data:
[image]

I am grouping to remove duplicate records the problem is that the employee name is registered in a different way

The expected result is this, so that it always returns the employee name with the largest number of characters

[image]

this is my query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT [ID_Country] ,[Year_] ,[Employee_ID] ,MAX([Employee_Name]) AS Employee_Name
FROM Employee_Tbl
GROUP BY [ID_Country],[Year_],[Employee_ID]
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to do the query and it always returns the employee name with the largest number of characters?

Comment: What is your question here? You imply you have an attempt but it isn't working; what is that attempt, why isn't is working? What are your expected results here?

Comment: I want to group by the columns [ID_Country],[Year_],[Employee_ID] to remove duplicate records and from the Employee_Name column bring the name of the employee with the highest number of characters if there is the same number of characters bring the first record

Comment: the question is how can I make my query always return the name that has more characters

Comment: But that's what I mean, what is "first"? Ordered by what? A table is an unordered bag of rows, so let's make sure a solution considers "first" the same way you do. (Also, `DISTINCT` _and_ `GROUP BY` really, really, really don't ever belong together.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a row number based on country and year, ranked by the length of the name descending:

```
SELECT ID_Country, Year_, Employee_ID, Employee_Name
FROM
(
  SELECT ID_Country, Year_, Employee_ID, Employee_Name, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
      PARTITION BY ID_Country, Year_ 
      ORDER BY LEN(Employee_Name) DESC, Employee_ID
    )
  FROM dbo.Employee_Tbl
) AS Employees WHERE rn = 1;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=443c1476322da340414217fbd101f306)

There is some guessing there about how you'd want to break ties (or maybe you don't care), but there is no concept of "first" unless you state an order explicitly.